# What is the Big-O performance of this algorithm and how do I solve this normally?

Tags: python, algorithm

Hello I have an algorithm that I am having trouble with finding the performance.

```
 i=math.ceil(n**0.5)
 while n % i != 0: 
  i -= 2
```

Would this be O(2^n)?

Comment: what is this supposed to be solving?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but your current code will run give error **cannot divide by zero** for many cases for example for `n=13`, but if you do `i-=1` in place of `i-=2` then your code will work fine without any error for every `n` and complexity would be `O(n^(1\2))`.

Comment: Could you explain how you got this?  What would it be with the i -= 2 in place?

Comment: It won't loop forever as you cannot divide by 0

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yeah was just about to correct that

Comment: @church I made an edit. It will not run infinite but give error because for n=13 initially i=4 then i becomes 2 and then i becomes 0 and n%0 will give error cannot divide by zero.

Comment: @Crunch The way to get the O(n^(1/2)) is by looking at the loop. You start at i=n^(1/2) and decrease it linearly every iteration. Therefore the complexity (performance as you put it) is O(n^(1/2). Whether you decrease i by 1 or 2 doesn't impact the Big-O complexity.